# Puzzling KeyEvent handling for lowercase letters

Tags: javafx, keyevent

If I set up a `KeyEvent` handler as below, the behaviour is as I would expect, and as the Oracle documentation seems to specify, for uppercase letters and Ascii characters that are not letters or digits.

However, for lowercase letters, if I hold down the Ctrl key when typing the letter, the `EventHandler` seems to fail to register the keypress at all.

This is shown by the output below, from typing Q, q, $, Ctrl+Q, Ctrl+q, Ctrl+$ in sequence.

Can anyone shed light upon this behaviour?   Am I missing something?   I have searched but not found any other references to this question.

```
import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.stage.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.event.*;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;

// Test handling keypresses of upper and lower case letter, and non-alphameric ascii symbol,
// to see if any difference exists when Ctrl is held down
// between the handling for (ev.isShortcutDown()) and (ev.isMetaDown() || ev.isControlDown())
// and between the three character types

// Program to be tested by typing, in sequence,
//              Q  q  $  Ctrl+Q  Ctrl+q  Ctrl+$


public class TestHandlingKeyEvents extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());
        stage.setScene(scene);

        EventHandler<KeyEvent> handleUserTyping = ev -> {

            String charTyped = ev.getCharacter();
            switch (charTyped) {
                case "Q":               // quit
                    System.out.println("\nQ typed ");
                    if (ev.isShortcutDown()) 
                        System.out.println("with Shortcut down ");
                    if (ev.isMetaDown() || ev.isControlDown())
                        System.out.println("with Meta or Ctrl down ");
                    break;                  
                case "q":               // complete reset
                    System.out.println("\nq typed ");
                    if (ev.isShortcutDown()) 
                        System.out.println("with Shortcut down ");
                    if (ev.isMetaDown() || ev.isControlDown())
                        System.out.println("with Meta or Ctrl down ");              
                    break;
                case "$":               // back to last view
                    System.out.println("\n$ typed ");
                    if (ev.isShortcutDown()) 
                        System.out.println("with Shortcut down ");
                    if (ev.isMetaDown() || ev.isControlDown())
                        System.out.println("with Meta or Ctrl down ");              
                    break;
            }
        };

        scene.setOnKeyTyped(handleUserTyping);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

And the output:

```
john@jlaptop2:/java$ java TestHandlingKeyEvents

Q typed 

q typed 

$ typed 

Q typed 
with Shortcut down 
with Meta or Ctrl down 

$ typed 
with Shortcut down 
with Meta or Ctrl down 
john@jlaptop2:/java$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong type of event to get the behavior you wish.

Read up on the various types of KeyEvents in the [KeyEvent javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyEvent.html).

Basically you can register event handlers on KEY_PRESSED events rather than KEY_TYPED events.  The key typed events are only generated when the underlying system registers a unicode character being generated through typing, which is not the case for some of the key input sequences you are trying to capture.  To capture more input character sequences that aren't necessarily related to unicode character generation, the lower level KEY_PRESSED (or KEY_RELEASED) events are the ones to use.

Still, there is a higher level interface than this that you can use and may be more appropriate for your use case, which is to set accelerators based upon [KeyCodeCombinations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyCodeCombination.html).

*Sample using Accelerators*

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.ObservableMap;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCombination;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

// Test handling keypresses of upper and lower case letter, 
// and non-alphameric ascii symbol.    
// Program to be tested by typing, in sequence,
//              Ctrl+Q  Ctrl+q  Ctrl+$    
public class TestHandlingKeyAccelerators extends Application {    
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());
        stage.setScene(scene);

        ObservableMap<KeyCombination, Runnable> accelerators = 
                scene.getAccelerators();

        accelerators.put(
                KeyCombination.valueOf("Ctrl+Q"), 
                () -> System.out.println("Ctrl+q -> reset")
        );
        accelerators.put(
                KeyCombination.valueOf("Ctrl+Shift+Q"), 
                () -> System.out.println("Ctrl+Q -> quit")
        );
        accelerators.put(
                KeyCombination.valueOf("Ctrl+Shift+'4'"), 
                () -> System.out.println("Ctrl+$ -> back to last view")
        );

        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Notice how the [KeyCombination.valueO](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyCombination.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-)f method is used to construct key combinations.  Also note how (except for '4' which identifies a character) each key is identified by its keycode.  As, on my keyboard, lowercase q and uppercase Q are the same key, but a shift is used to generate the upper case key, then Ctrl+q is encoded as Ctrl+Q, and Ctrl+Q is encoded as Ctrl+Shift+Q.  Also, my keyboard has no dollar key, but instead a dollar is generated by pressing shift and the four key.  Usually the four key code would be DIGIT4, but, for some reason, that doesn't work in this case.  So to get Ctrl+$ operation I use Ctrl+Shift+'4' to signify the control and shift modifiers for when a key that generates the character '4' is pressed.

*Comment on the operation of your original sample*

Also, as a side note which is mostly trivia, when tested on a Mac (2012 MacBook Air OS X 10.11.4, Java 8u60), your program gives different output, likely due to a different keyboard system or OS handling of key events.  The output on a Mac for your suggested key sequence is:

```
Q typed 

q typed 

$ typed
```

The following output sequence which you show in your question is not produced on a Mac:

```
Q typed 
with Shortcut down 
with Meta or Ctrl down 

$ typed 
with Shortcut down 
with Meta or Ctrl down
```